# Ansible - conditional execution of a specific task inside a role

Tags: ansible, docker-swarm

I have a cluster of 6 nodes on which I want to create a docker swarm using Ansible.

In the Ansible inventory, the nodes have names rpi102 to rpi107, and node rpi105 is initialised as swarm master (with *swarm init*). The manager and worker tokens are stored as in the facts of rpi105 as *manager_token* and *worker_token* respectively. rpi105 is the **only** node in the inventory that has these two facts, I am 100% sure of that (as shown from the output of the two DEBUG tasks below).

After rpi105 is initialised as swarm master, the playbook runs the following role:

```
---
- name: Find the swarm master and store its node name in facts of the current node
  set_fact:
    swarm_master: "{{ hostvars[item]['ansible_nodename'] }}"
  when: hostvars[item]['manager_token'] is defined
  with_items: "{{ groups['rpicloud'] }}"

- name: DEBUG - manager swarm token
  debug:
    var: hostvars['rpi105']['manager_token']

- name: DEBUG - Check if any other node has "manager_token"
  debug:
    msg: "Node: {{ inventory_hostname }}, Token: {{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['manager_token'] }}"
  when: hostvars[inventory_hostname]['manager_token'] is defined

- name: Print swarm master hostname
  debug:
    var: hostvars[inventory_hostname]['swarm_master']
  when: hostvars[inventory_hostname]['swarm_master'] is defined
```

The first task iterates all the nodes in the inventory looking for the one that has a *manager_token* fact, and stores the name of this node in its own facts. I.e. all nodes should end up having a fact *swarm_master* that contains *rpi105*.

The output of the second task (DEBUG one) for each node is:

> ok: [rpi104] => {
> "hostvars['rpi105']['manager_token']": {
> "changed": true,
> "cmd": "docker swarm join-token --quiet manager",
> "delta": "0:00:00.076792",
> "end": "2022-10-25 19:18:54.280418",
> "failed": false,
> "msg": "",
> "rc": 0,
> "start": "2022-10-25 19:18:54.203626",
> "stderr": "",
> "stderr_lines": [],
> "stdout": "SWMTKN-1-2e4fuosjynxyiu725oqxsb95mg4btxy9iqa4mrkn0dahvbm9v0-8lw6x0jz81xc4ew6wcgx8f90r",
> "stdout_lines": [
> "SWMTKN-1-2e4fuosjynxyiu725oqxsb95mg4btxy9iqa4mrkn0dahvbm9v0-8lw6x0jz81xc4ew6wcgx8f90r"
> ]
> } }

And the output of the third task (also DEBUG) for each node (rpi105 skips this role) is:

> ok: [rpi107] => {
> "msg": "Node: rpi107, Token: {'changed': False, 'skipped': True, 'skip_reason': 'Conditional result was False'}" }

The fourth task prints what each node is actually storing, which is:

> ok: [rpi102] => {
> "hostvars[inventory_hostname]['swarm_master']": "rpi107" }

i.e. all nodes are storing the name of the last node in the iteration.
Why is this?, why is task 1 executing for all nodes regardless of the *when* condition?

Oct25th, 2022 -> I have edited the original message to add two debug task and provide the info requested in some of the comments.

Comment: Whats the output for the first task against each host? do they all show as `ok` or are all showing as `skipping` other than rpi105?

Comment: "rpi105 is the only node in the inventory that has these two facts, I am 100% sure of that." Can you add some debug output to your question that verifies that? Because that fact not being true would be a simple explanation for the behavior you've described. This question would be easier for us if it included a [mcve] -- a runnable playbook that reproduces the problematic behavior. There's a lot you haven't shown us, which makes it hard for us to answer.

Comment: > i.e. all nodes are storing the name of the last node in the iteration. Why is this?, why is task 1 executing for all nodes regardless of the when condition?

It seems that task1 is executing for all nodes *because* of the when condition, if all the elements in the _rpicloud_ group have a _manager_token_ defined, they will set the fact _swarm_master_ several times, as that variable is getting overridden, the value it will display is going to be from the last iteration

Comment: thanks for all the comments. I just edited the content to add debugging information.